# How can I get objects to maintain their order

Tags: javascript, object

I know this has been talked about and I have tried many examples with no avail. Guessing I have a no win here but I want one last go at it, so I'll ask good old StackOverflow.

Here is an example STRING I have

```
{"X":"545","20":"1","22":"1","25":"1","26":"1","27.5":"1","28.5":"1","29.875":"1","32":"1"}
```

When I stuff this in to an object using eval or parseJSON I get the following object

Opera, FF, Chrome, Safari

```
{"X":"545","20":"1","22":"1","25":"1","26":"1","27.5":"1","28.5":"1","29.875":"1","32":"1"}
```

Ie 7-9

```
{"20":"1","22":"1","25":"1","26":"1","32":"1","X":"545","27.5":"1","28.5":"1","29.875":"1"}
```

Now I know per definition there is no way to ensure an order. However every browser does maintain the order but good old IE. And we need IE to play fair.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If order matters, stuff these things into an array.

Comment: If the spec says there's no guaranteed order, then it would be a bad idea to rely on it even if **all** browsers maintained some particular order.

Comment: Regarding iterating, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description . Therefore I can't see any reason to use an object as the container if order matters

Answer (score 1):

Use an array for an ordered set of values.

By definition an Object is unordered. But you can still get your values by calling the right property, so it shouldn't matter much if you code accordingly.

Comment: I need this in an object because the table I'm stuffing it in only excepts an object. Each row is an object, the rows are an array. My table accepts JSON, so if there is a batter way to package my data maybe that is the key here. I though JSON is nothing more then an array of objects.

Comment: An array is an object :) Please give more specs regarding your code if you want a better answer, or you'll get flooded by "use array" answers. What does your table expects exactly?

Comment: I mentioned that in the above comment. "My table accepts JSON," How can I better format it so that it preserves order and is still JSON.

Comment: In this case, and if order matters, make your table expect an array. there is no way to expect a specific order from JSON, that's the way the standard is defined and not a browser issue. Sorry to disappoint :(

Comment: the tables part of an SDK I cont modify that? I'll see if it takes an array instead and work from there.

Comment: Mainly just curious on this, guessing there is no answer for it. I ungraded IE 9 to 10 and now all browsers that were in the correct order are doing it the way IE is. Again, I just found that remotely ironic...

Comment: yeah, sometimes the web is a very strange place ^^ This upgrade thing seems way weird! Anyway, hope I answered your initial question.